# Are there any good tools for reporting on a computer's specs?

Tags: desktop, diagnostic, specifications

I have a client who has a computer they want to upgrade.  They are unable to tell me the specs of this computer and they're not the type of person I could walk it through with.

Ideally, I'd like to send them an application (or a link to an application) which will generate a report telling me everything I need to know about their hardware and OS.  It would have to be *very* easy to use.  Ideally only two or three steps to generate a report.

Free is definitely better.  Any ideas?

Comment: This would probably get a better response on superuser.com

Comment: I don't think this question should be moved.

Comment: @Dennis - nope, didn't move it but I asked it on SuperUser as well for some other opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we use at my office for this purpose is PCWizard:

http://www.cpuid.com/pcwizard.php

It's free as in beer, and works very well.

Comment: Yes, free as in beer is what I meant :)

Comment: Installer tries to put the ask.com toolbar on the system.  Since you are having a client run it you should make sure to point out to them to uncheck this, no reason to stick extra junk on their PC.

Answer (score 5):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html)

Running the advisor on a PC will generate a report to a web browser.  Details cover both hardware and software of the machine with a very useful amount of detail (such as license keys for some software).

From that point you could have them print the page to PDF if they have something such as Adobe Acrobat or a 3rd party pdf printer installed, save the html page and email it to you, or simply print it and fax it to you.  Whatever you think your user would be most comfortable with.

Try running it on your own PC and check out the report results, there is a lot of good detail there.

Comment: Wow, that actually looks awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Open Audit is another free alternative; http://www.open-audit.org/standalone.php

Simple VB Script you can run/edit

Answer (score 0):

[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) is another good one.